# IOS: NSUserDefault for an array of UIImage

Tags: ios, xcode, nsuserdefaults, nskeyedarchiver

I want to store an array of UIImage and I do this:

```
//in didFinishLaunchingWithOption

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *data = [defaults objectForKey:@"theKey"];
if (data == NULL)  arrayImage = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
else {arrayImage = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; arrayImage = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];}
NSLog(@"arrayImage:%@", arrayImage);

//and in applicationDidEnterBackground

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:arrayImage];
[defaults setObject:data forKey:@"theKey"];
NSLog(@"arrayImage:%@", arrayImage);
```

when app run in didFinishLaunchingWithOption in nslog I see all object in my array, but when I use it, I have a crash that say "[__NSArrayM count]: message sent to deallocated instance" why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure, but I think that

> +(id)unarchiveObjectWithData:(NSData *)data

gives you an autoreleased object, so you may retain it. And I think it will give you a non-mutable object, so when you will try to add or remove objects from it you will get an error (I'm no sure about this, but I think I once was in this situation...)

I would rewrite some part of your code:

```
...
if (data == nil)
{
    arrayImage = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
} else
{
    //arrayImage = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; //why to allocate and initialize if you are goind to unarchive it?
    //arrayImage = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data] retain]; //note the retain here
    NSArray *arr = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data]; //the unarchive won't mantain mutability (I guess).
    arrayImage = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arr]; //create a mutable copy
}
...
```

Comment: I forgot the retain message to my last approach! You should replace the last instruction with any of these:
    arrayImage = [[NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arr] retain];
or
    arrayImage = [arr mutableCopy];

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're not using ARC. The problem is in:

```
if (data == NULL)
  arrayImage = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
else {
  arrayImage = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
  // HERE
  arrayImage = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
}
```

At `HERE`, you replace the value in `arrayImage` with a new instance for the keyed unarchiver. The value you `init`'d just previously is lost (in fact, leaked). The value from the unarchiver is an autoreleased object, so will be released when the pool is drained. This is before the `applicationDidEnterBackground` call is made.

The correct solution is to retain the value from the unarchiver. Viz:

```
if (data == nil)
  arrayImage = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
else
  arrayImage = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data] retain];
```

Comment: it's the same thing, I have the same problem with or without "arrayImage = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];"